# A relative cycle class map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, algebraic-cycles

Suppose I have a smooth projective morphism $p: X \to S$ between varieties, and a relative cycle $Z \subset X \to S$ which is assumed to be as nice as can be (rquidimensional with fibers of dimension $d$, smooth etc). In this setting, there should exist a (ell-adic) cycle class map sending Z to an element in $R^{2d}p_*\mathbb Q_\ell(-d) $, correct? What's a reference for this?

Moreover, is the action of geometric monodromy group $\pi_1(\overline S)$, where we base change to an algebraic closure, trivial on the image of the cycle class map trivial?

Comment: a stupid question: What is the target of the cycle class map considered in the question? The usual derived category of constructible sheaves? (...or do you tacitly impose some additional structure for the target? eg $D$-module structure...

Comment: This sounds correct. The action of $\pi_1(\overline{S})$ need not be trivial (think about $d=0$, $Z=X$ and $p$  étale ), but I think it should  act through a finite quotient. Sorry I don't have a good reference, most standard sources when $S$ is  point.

Comment: @user267839 in happy with the usual derived category of constructible sheaves, although the question is interesting in other settings too.

Comment: @DonuArapura Ah I thought about that case too and confused myself into believing the action is trivial. But finite quotient is probably good enough for my application! I was surprised to not find any references either.